# How to remap ESC key to CAPS LOCK in VsVIM in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, vsvim

I used to use Vim in Ubuntu. Now use Visual Studio in Windows. I am relatively new to Visual studio. I have installed VsVim extension and want to remap ESC key to CAPS LOCK to quit insert mode and get into Normal mode. How to customize this?

Answer (score 1):

I use a registry key edit for this (details below). But an AutoHotKey script would also work.

Here's the registry change (put it in a file with a `.reg` extension and launch it to apply). It changes the CAPSLOCK key to behave like an ESC key.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,01,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

https://github.com/jcouv/dotfiles/blob/master/remap-caps-lock.reg

I'm not sure how this work. I used a tool called ScanMapSet (http://benf.org/other/scanmapset/index.html) to change my mapping then copied the value it had set in the registry.